# How to hide a checkbox in JS Tree Library

Tags: jquery, css, jstree

I need to hide some of the checkboxes rendered through JSTree library.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li id="folder_1">Folder 1
            <ul>
                <li id="child_1">Child 1</li>
                <li id="child_2">Child 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="folder_2">Folder 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tree").jstree({
        "checkbox": {
            "keep_selected_style": false
        },
            "plugins": ["checkbox"]
    });
    $("#tree").bind("changed.jstree",
    function (e, data) {
        alert("Checked: " + data.node.id);
        alert("Parent: " + data.node.parent); 
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```

I need to hide the the checkbox (Child 2)in Folder 1 but have the child 2 displayed but without checkboxes. I'm including a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gdonarum/47d6r/).

Comment: @VTodorov Thanks for re-organizing my question. I mark this as input for my next questions.

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you really want. Do you want no checkboxes for the two child objects or only for Child 2?

Comment: Only for Child 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a css class to remove the checkbox.

`<li id="" class="no-checkbox">Child 2</li>`

CSS:

```
.no-checkbox i.jstree-checkbox {
  display:none;
}
```

Here is a [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/w85w87rt/)

Comment: If I could disable the hidden checkbox as well, as when the parent check box is checked it shows all the sub nodes are selected. The basis idea for hiding the checkbox was not to allow user to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer given by VTodorov helped to me, but it will disable all parent checkboxes.

So here the improved approach

CSS:

```
.no-checkbox > a > i.jstree-checkbox {
   display:none;
}
```